# Why am I getting a NotSupportedException in WP7 Silveright using oDAta?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, odata

I have a WCF Service set up on my web site with a service. I can access all of the data I am trying to obtain using a web browser. When I navigate around I can filter and get to any part of the data I need, so the feed seems to be set up correctly.

When I try to access this data using my auto-generated oData service reference I am running into an issue where it gives me a not supported exception as soon as I try to enumerate either the IQuerable or the DataServiceQuery.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong that is getting me this NotSupportedException?

**Notes:** This is currently running locally. The web site is a .NET 4 app. I am using the OData Client Library for Windows Phone 7 series from [here](http://www.odata.org/developers/odata-sdk). When I run this code from a console application it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running it asynchronously? Silverlight needs requires that requests are made asynchronously.

Comment: Ha! Thanks Daniel. Well, this should help someone else in the future.